# Show objects without tibble information (R)

Tags: r, output, tibble, appearance

I have the following problem.

When I was looking up a specific value it usually looked like this:

```
df1[383,54]
[1] "This is a Test-String."
```

But when I load something from excel:

```
library(readxl)
df2 <- read_excel("~/Test.xls", col_names = FALSE)
```

It started looking like this:

```
df1[383,54]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
               X__54
               <chr>
1 This is a Test-String.
```

What have I done wrong? It is not because of the tibble package, because when I detach it, it is the same output. Why does the output of my dataframe change, when I load a different dataset. I tried a lot but did not find an answer. Hopefully this is not a question with an overly obvious answer.

Comment: What is the problem with the output other than it is a column in a `tbl_df` If you want to get the same format extract with `[[` i.e.  `df1[[54]][383]`  You can check the `str(df1)` and `str(df2)`  The difference is the classes, i.e. the first one is just a `data.frame` but the second one has additional features i.e. `tbl_df`

Comment: Why would you think it isn't because of the package?  The package loads that function which returns a tibble instead of a data.frame.

Comment: @Dason Yes, I realized, that it was because of the package. The problem is, that also after detaching the package nothing changes.

Comment: @D.P. Why would it? The data is already loaded. I'm not sure what you think would change after detaching the package?

Comment: `read_excel` reads in a tibble.  Detaching the readxl package doesn't change the fact that the data is still a tibble.  Working with tibbles is similar but slightly different than working with data.frames. You can read more about them here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html

Answer (score 1):

`df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)` should prevent the header from showing by changing from a tibble back to a standard data.frame.